# awk as vlookup between two files

Tags: awk

I have the following 2 files tab separated:

file1:

```
KEY1    TEXT1
KEY2    TEXT2
KEY3    TEXT3
```

file2:

```
KEY1    111
KEY2    222
KEY3    333
```

I would like to achieve the following where "aaa", "bbb" are static text:

```
aaa TEXT1   bbb 111 ccc KEY1    ddd
aaa TEXT2   bbb 222 ccc KEY2    ddd
aaa TEXT3   bbb 333 ccc KEY3    ddd
```

I'm running the following code:

```
 awk -F'\t' -f vlookup.awk file1 file2
```

where vlookup.awk is:

```
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
{ if ($1 in a) { print "aaa", a[$1], "bbb", $2} else {print $1, "ERROR"}}
```

which works for the first part but as soon as I add `"ccc", $1, "ddd"` the results are messed-up like:

```
aaa cccXT1  KEY111ddd1
```

Kind regards
dk

Comment: what do you mean by *as soon as I add "ccc"*?   what, **exactly**, did you add to the awk script?   (the print statement should be `print "aaa", a[$1], "bbb", $2, "ccc", $1, "ddd"` - was it anything like that).  Also, what do you mean by *the results are messed-up*?  show sample "messed up" output.

Comment: Corrected. I also found the error, one of the two files had new line character mixed sometimes with `\r\n` sometimes with `\n`. replacing everything with `\n` solved it.

Comment: The example data that you show just needs to be paired up line-by-line. Is this always the case? If not, consider showing an example where there are missing keys in one file, or duplicate or out-of-order keys in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat vlookup.awk 
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
#{ if ($1 in a) { print "aaa", a[$1], "bbb", $2} else {print $1, "ERROR"}}
{ if ($1 in a)  { print "aaa", a[$1], "bbb", $2, "ccc", $1, "ddd" } else {print $1, "ERROR"}}
```

```
$ awk -F'\t' -f vlookup.awk file1 file2
aaa     TEXT1   bbb     111     ccc     KEY1    ddd
aaa     TEXT2   bbb     222     ccc     KEY2    ddd
aaa     TEXT3   bbb     333     ccc     KEY3    ddd
```

Comment: I have found the error, one of the lists has a new line mixed sometimes with `\r\n` sometimes with `\n` and this was causing the error when i was adding the final part "ccc" ...